# Search data from spreadsheet and show in html form with google web app script

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script

I have an excel spreadsheet table with column name - id ,name,fathers_name,marks .We want search particular data from spreadsheet and show in any html page.

We use this code :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Your Spread Sheet URL");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  

function doPost(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  


function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id;

  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i = 0;i<values.length; i++){

    if(values[i][0] == id ){
      i=i+2;

      var name = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(name).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

}
```

But this line give error -

```
var id = e.parameter.id;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 14, file "Code")Dismiss

Please help me ?? How solve this error ??

Comment: How are you trying this code ? I'm afraid you are missing some fundamentals about how to setup web application and Google apps script. Please give more information.

Comment: Did you publish this as a web app?